# Como converter XML para objectos em Swift?

Tags: xml, swift, objetos, parser, conversão

Como posso converter respostas de requisições no formato XML para objetos em Swift, assim como o ObjectMapper faz com JSON para objetos?

Comment: Da uma olhada, possa ser que te ajude https://github.com/drmohundro/SWXMLHash

Comment: Sim é consegui usar esse mesmo, é o melhor :D. Coloca sua sugestão como resposta e eu aceito! Abraço e Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa implementar o `NSXMLParserDelegate`:

Declare duas variáveis globais

```
var xmlParser: NSXMLParser!
var currentContentElement: NSMutableString!
```

Depois no método que recebe a resposta da requisição SOAP você chama o `xmlParser`

```
xmlParser = NSXMLParser(data: responseData)
xmlParser.delegate = self
xmlParser.parse()
```

Implementação do `NSXMLParserDelegate`:

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {
    self.currentContentElement = NSMutableString()
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
    self.currentContentElement.appendString(string)
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
    switch elementName {
    case "CAMPOXXXX":
        let variavelxxx = currentContentElement.integerValue
        break
    default:
        break
    }
    self.currentContentElement = nil
}

func parserDidEndDocument(parser: NSXMLParser) {

}
```

É muito simples no método `didEndElement` você pega os valores que você precisa e joga no seu objeto.

Espero ter te ajudado =D